# Configuration error while running tests in TestNG through eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

While I was running my tests through `TestNG`, I am getting the error mentioned below. Can anyone help me in getting this resolved?

> org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getClasspath(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/util/List;

Comment: You should proved other related information like version of eclipse, testng, how you are running for example running through maven pom or as testng test through eclipse etc.

Comment: Am running through TestNG test in eclipse.                                             
 Version: Mars Release (4.5.0) Build id: 20150621-1200.                                                          
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

Answer (score -1):

Today I had a same issue and solved with below steps.

While installing TestNG, please uncheck the chck box for M2E Maven related one and continue the installation process.
Restart the Eclipse and execute a test case....